# How to send a form key with post data using ajax to a controller in magento?

Tags: magento-1, ajax, form-key

Suppose I have an ajax function like this in a separate js file

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/package/module/index/index",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: user_name, dob: date_of_birth},//here i want to send a form key used in magento
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

My controller is like this

```
Class Package_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
        //stufss to do here
    }
}
```

In above php controller I want to validate request with a magento form key.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use js in external file then you need to add below code in any top of head.phtml file

```
var formKey = "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>";
```

Then add your js code as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/package/module/index/index",
    type: "POST",
    data: {form_key:formKey name: user_name, dob: date_of_birth},//here i want to send a form key used in magento
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to call form key block like below in form html:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

For passing it in ajax call you can defined form serialize in data parameter of ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "/package/module/index/index",
type: "POST",
data: jQuery('#Your_form_id').serialize() + "&name="+user_name+"&par2="+date_of_birth
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
});
```

need add username and dob additionally only if both are not defined in form.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
jQuery("#form_id").on("submit", function(event) {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/package/module/index/index",
    type: "POST",
    data: jQuery(this).serialize(),//here i want to send a form key used in magento
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get form_key

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$key_form = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');
$form_Key = $key_form->getFormKey(); 
?>
```

Javascript code

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="Test()">Javascript</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Test(){

          var request_data = 'id=125&form_key=<?php echo $form_Key; ?>';

          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var url = data.redirect;
                if(url!=''){
                  window.location.href = data.redirect;
                }
            }
          };

          xhttp.open("POST", "your_path", true);
          //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhttp.send(request_data);
  }
</script>
```

ccontroller code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Login;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{



    protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {

        $this->data = $_REQUEST;
        print_r($this->data);
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }




    public function execute()
    {
        print_r($_REQUEST);

        echo '1';
        die();

    }
}
?>
```

Please check it will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: Add form_key from template file

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Second: add form key to param

```
var formKey = jQuery('#Your_form_id').value;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/package/module/index/index",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: user_name, dob: date_of_birth, form_key:formKey},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Third: Get form key from pram (I think you know :) )